# It says "unexpected token" when using Google maps the same way as presented in the documentation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, google-maps-api-3

I am using the code provided by Google on their website to implement Google Maps API into my code. Now, this is Reactjs, and they are using it within the index.js file while I am using it in a separate component, so that might be the reason behind the error.

Here is [a link to their code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/react-map), and if you scroll down, you will see the complete code (no explanations) [in code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/sample-react-map). Now I will show you how I am implementing it down below.

Here is my code for [the father component](https://pastebin.com/8rhzh9ym) (the component that I will call the map component), and here is [the actual component](https://pastebin.com/X03yqLWH) (the child) where I implement the map API, which it will be called to the father.

[image]

I do not know what to do there, so I have tried to implement the fundamentals of code for it as Google has, but when I do, my screen goes blank. And I mean when I use this:

```
const Map: React.FC<{}> = () => {};
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: maybe it needs an initial value?

Comment: @jamal such as? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: An empty object or data as type of the `google.maps.Map`

Comment: @Jamal, ok, so basically, I am sending an empty object, you are saying. Yes, so how do I initialize google maps then... they do now have examples in there too on the initialization of maps..